# Bar Chart(height) not equal

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

i tried a bar chart with add a value labels from my csv file and its work but i got a problem why the height of the bar chart is not equal?

***CSV file :***
CPU_5_SEC;CPU_1_MIN;CPU_5_MIN;
27;17;16;

***Code :***

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 3
men_std=(0,1,2)

data = np.loadtxt('show-process-cpu.csv',dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=(0,1,2))
utilization= data[1]

label = np.loadtxt('show-process-cpu.csv',dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=(0,1,2)).astype(str)
my_xticks = label[0]

ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.40

rects = plt.bar(ind, utilization, width ,men_std,color='r',)

plt.title("Cpu Utilization\n ('%') ")
plt.xticks(ind,my_xticks)

def autolabel(rects):

    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2,height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you removed your comment on my answer? I was notified but now it's gone. Please let me know if it worked and, if it did, accept the answer.

Comment: sorry for the late reply :), i tried and its worked, thanks :)

Comment: np! I appreciate it, but in SO we mainly thank the correct/best answer [by accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), which rewards the poster and informs others that the issue is solved.

Comment: yes, thanks for information :)
i'm new in here, so i a little bit confused hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ax.bar` second argument needs to be an array of integers. I also removed `men_std=(0,1,2)` argument and definition, since this makes the bars to be plotted in different heights.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 3

data = np.loadtxt('show-process-cpu.csv',dtype=bytes, delimiter=';', usecols=(0,1,2))

my_xticks = data[0]
utilization = data[1]
utilization_int = [int(x) for x in utilization]

ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.40

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, utilization_int, width,color='r',)

ax.set_title("Cpu Utilization\n ('%') ")
ax.set_xticks(ind)
ax.set_xticklabels(my_xticks)

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2,height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
plt.show()
```

[image]